# Repeat when keeping hold pressIn button on React native

Tags: react-native

- Based on https://medium.com/@pavolfulop/repeat-onpress-action-when-holding-button-react-native-2c697cf28032, I want to repeat something when keeping hold press button on React Native. This solution work for class component. But it does not work for function component use useState hook. In this example, if you use function component and use useState hook for number. It not work.
- Does anybody have solution for the function component?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
const timer = useRef(null);
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const addOne = () => {
 setCounter((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);
 // 15.05.2023 EDIT: clear timer.current if already exists
 // to avoid potential floating timer on user double click
 if (timer.current) clearTimeout(timer.current!);
 // set new timer
 timer.current = setTimeout(addOne, 200);
}

const stopTimer = () => {
 clearTimeout(timer.current);
}

return (
<TouchableOpacity onPressIn={addOne} onPressOut={stopTimer}>
  <Text>+</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <View 
        style={styles.button} 
        onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true} 
        onResponderStart={() => functionCalledOnMouseDown}
        onResponderRelease={() => functionCalledOnMouseUp}
    >
```

You will still need to write the looping function to happen while mouse is down but I believe you can achieve what you're looking for using View tags styled as buttons.